# O que é gerúndio e em quais casos deve ser aplicado?

Tags: gramática, verbos, tempo-verbal, forma-verbal, gerúndios

Gerúndio não é um tempo verbal, certo? O que ele é então?

Quando pensamos em gerúndio, sempre imaginamos o exemplo de uma ação presente em curso:

- Eu estou **caminhando**.

Mas ele também ocorre em diversas outras situações.

Exemplo:

- Volte para a nossa página inicial, **clicando** aqui.
- O professor explicou, **sorrindo**, a matéria de hoje.

Os verbos "**sorrindo**" e "**clicando**" estão no gerúndio, mas não há ação presente em curso.

O mesmo fato ocorre em:

- **Sendo** assim, vamos agir desta forma.

Ou ainda em:

- Amanhã, das oito às nove, não me ligue, pois vou estar **dirigindo**.

Quais essas situações (talvez eu tenha me esquecido de alguma que não exemplifiquei acima) e quais as diferenças entre elas?

Comment: Se o gerúndio não for um tempo verbal, como dizes na primeira frase, como é que os verbos "sorrindo" e "clicando" podem estar no gerúndio? Se verbos estiverem no gerúndio, não implica isso que o gerúndio é um tempo verbal?

Comment: Pois é... posso estar incorreto, mas foi o que li nos sites de gramátia pela internet. O ingês tem um tempo verbal chamado "present continuous" que é bem semelhante, mas em Portugues parece que é diferente. Não se chama gerúndio de tempo verbal. Estou em busca de uma explicação técnica para o assunto.

Comment: O gerúndio é uma forma nominal do verbo e, em regra, dá sentido de continuidade. No caso do gerúndio, além do valor verbal, ele também pode desempenhar a função de advérbio ou adjetivo. Na frase 1, temos uma locução verbal que passa a ideia de continuidade; na 2, poderá substituir por "quando clicar aqui", neste caso terá valor de adv. temporal; na 3, temos o valor de advérbio de modo; na 4, o "sendo assim" é utilizado como uma locução conjuntiva coordenada explicativa ou conclusiva (podemos trocar por portanto); na 5, temos um tempo composto, que indica uma ação simultânea a outra no futuro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como foi dito nos comentários, o gerúndio e o particípio são formas nominais do verbo.

As formas nominais do verbo **não** flexionam em número, pessoa, voz, aspecto, modo, tempo. Por não terem flexão, têm uma unica forma. O gerúndio e o particípio são relativamente mais fáceis de usar, porque dispensam saber as variações da flexão verbal. Pode comparar a diferença em número das flexões verbais neste exemplo: [flexões do verbo correr](https://dicionario.priberam.org/Conjugar/correr)

Quanto às diferenças nos exemplos de utilização do gerúndio que foram dados, a maioria são diferenças de sintaxe, ou seja, da forma como constrói a frase.

No entanto, podemos salientar, como principal diferença, os casos em que o gerúndio foi usado com um verbo auxiliar: `ser` ou `estar`.

Exemplo:

> - estou caminhando
> - estar dirigindo

Esta utilização sobressai especialmente no contraste entre o Português Europeu e do Brasil. O gerúndio com verbo auxiliar é raramente usado no Português Europeu, mas muito usado no Português do Brasil. Tanto que pode ser considerado um forte indicador da nacionalidade do escritor.

Em geral, os professores de Português nas escolas em Portugal proíbem o uso do gerúndio com verbo auxiliar (dão como razão o uso do gerúndio com verbo auxiliar simplificar demasiado o verbo por dispensar as flexões, o que por sua vez cria uma tendência de homogeneidade no discurso, pois o falante tenderá a refugiar-se no uso do gerúndio em vez de optar por construções de frase mais complexas/variadas).