# Valor sintático de gerúndios e particípios

Tags: verbos, sintaxe, gerúndios, forma-verbal, função-sintática

Minha dúvida é simples: Quando me deparar com uma forma nominal (particípio ou gerúndio) de um verbo em uma oração, como posso saber distinguir se ela integra locução verbal ou se assume função sintática de adjetivo ou advérbio (no caso específico do gerúndio):

Exemplo: em "A senhora agradeceu chorando a oferenda dos fiéis", como posso ter certeza de que "chorando" é advérbio e não parte da suposta locução verbal "agradeceu chorando"?

Comment: Por favor tome cuidado. Apesar do que diz a resposta com maior quantidade de votos positivos, verbos no gerúndio podem ser advérbios: [1](https://www.todamateria.com.br/gerundio/) [2](https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/morf/morf60.php) [3](https://beduka.com/blog/materias/portugues/o-que-e-gerundio/) [4](https://www.clubedoportugues.com.br/o-que-sao-as-formas-nominais-de-um-verbo/) [5](https://brasilescola.uol.com.br/gramatica/gerundio.htm) [6](https://www.conjugacao.com.br/gerundio/)

Comment: @GuiImamura Se ve claramente a sua intenção apesar de não me mencionar. Eu chamei o trecho de *locução **adverbial*** porque descreve como a tal senhora agradeceu. **O trecho inteiro qualifica como ela agradeceu e não somente a palavra "chorando"**. O menino respondeu botando as mãos na cabeça.

Answer (score 0):

"chorando" não pode ser advérbio. Tem de ser um verbo. Mas o trecho inteiro funciona como advérbio porque qualifica como ela os agradeceu.

Isso se chama **locução adverbial**

> Chamamos de locução adverbial um conjunto de duas ou mais palavras
> que, quando agrupadas, desempenham função de advérbio, podendo alterar
> o sentido de um verbo, de um adjetivo ou de um advérbio.

Nesse caso, **o sentido do verbo** "agradeceu" fica diferente ou modificado por causa da locução adverbial. Descreve **como** ela fez o gesto.

[definição](https://mundoeducacao.uol.com.br/gramatica/locucao-adverbial.htm)

Comment: No exemplo, "chorando" não pode ser locução adverbial porque uma locução, por definição, [é uma expressão formada por duas ou mais palavras](https://www.todamateria.com.br/locucao-adverbial/).

Comment: Além disso, gerúndios podem ser advérbios; fontes [1](https://beduka.com/blog/materias/portugues/o-que-e-gerundio/) [2](https://brasilescola.uol.com.br/gramatica/gerundio.htm) e [comentário de @ValdeirPsr](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/6390)

Comment: @GuiImamura exatamente: "oferenda dos fiéis" são tres palavras.

Comment: Não entendo aonde deseja chegar.

Comment: @GuiImamura Meu error. São quatro palavras. Seu primeiro comentário citou: uma expressão formada por duas ou mais palavras: "chorando a oferenda dos fiéis": quatro palavras

Comment: Os termos "a oferenda dos fiéis" são nítidamente o objeto direto do verbo transitivo [*agradecer*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/agradecer).

Comment: @GuiImamura Não. "chorando a oferenda dos fiéis" vai tudo junto. Eis a locução verbal. Ela agradaceu **como**? chorando a oferenda dos fiéis. Advérbio. Pois qualifica **como** ela agradeceu.

Comment: Afial se trata de locução adverbial como consta em sua resposta, ou de locução verbal como está dizendo em comentários na minha resposta?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150696/discussion-between-gui-imamura-and-lambie).

Answer (score 0):

Locuções verbais são formadas por uma expressão composta por dois verbos que denotam uma única ação [¹](https://www.todamateria.com.br/locucao-verbal/) [²](https://www.normaculta.com.br/locucoes-verbais/). Um dos verbos é auxiliar e é conjugado, enquanto o outro é o verbo principal e aparece em sua forma nominal.

- poderá sair
- começou a gritar

o que não é o caso do exemplo da pergunta, pois *agradecer* e *chorar* são duas ações distintas.

Neste caso, o **verbo no gerúndio *chorando* é advérbio** e qualifica o outro verbo *agradeceu*.

Comment: A locução verbal são quatro palavras: "chorando a oferenda dos fiéis"|

Comment: A minha definição vem de fonte confiável: https://mundoeducacao.uol.com.br/gramatica/locucao-adverbial.htm

Comment: Você mandou a definição de locuções **adverbiais**; o que o autor da pergunta perguntou sobre foi locução verbal, por isso escrevi sobre isso na resposta. Além disso, "a oferenda dos fiéis" é objeto direto do verbo *agradecer*.

Comment: Além disso, sua fonte é confiável mas sua interpretação é errônea: 1. interpretar "*chorando a oferenda dos fiéis*" como uma locução, desligando a relação entre verbo e objeto entre *agradecer* e *oferenda* mudaria completamente o sentido da frase; 2. locuções adverbiais exigem uma preposição ([1](https://brasilescola.uol.com.br/gramatica/locucoes-adverbiais.htm) e [2](https://www.todamateria.com.br/locucao-adverbial/)) e não é o caso da frase dada como exemplo; 3. seu comentário está na resposta errada e é sobre a sua própria resposta.

Comment: A frase se divide assim: /A senhora agradeceu/ chorando a oferenda dos fiéis/ A locução verbal começa com chorando e termina com fiéis.